# Standing water in dishwasher

Tags: water, dishwasher

I accidentally opened the diswasher mid-cycle. Then i closed it and it went back to normal operations. But after the cycle ended, i see some standing water at bottom on tub for the 1st time.

I quickly looked at airgap and it seems all clean to me.

Please let me know
1. If i can start the dishwasher again, and this water would go away on its own
2. If i need to do something else before starting the dishwasher again

Comment: Although there are several potential causes, a restriction in the drain line assembly is a common one. Make sure that the drain lines (from dishwasher to air-gap, from air-gap to drain line/disposer) are not kinked or plugged. If the air-gap drains to a garbage disposer make sure that there is no material blocking the disposer inlet (I have seen where material has been thrown up into the drain port inside the disposer, partially blocking it).

Answer (score 1):

I would try starting a short cycle and keep an eye on the drain that's inside the garbage disposal.  I have seen the short piece of drain line plug up with rice before.  Did you have a bunch of rice last meal?  Otherwise just let the short cycle run and peek into the disposal when you hear a drain cycle begin.  Also some units have filters at the bottom, you might want to check for that.

Answer (score 0):

On mine, when you press "Cancel", it runs a drain cycle for a period of time. I figure its running for an amount for which it hopes it all drains out. You could try starting a cycle and then pressing cancel immediately. Or, get a good grout sponge or similar and get the water out.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this once and it was because I’d replaced the sink disposal unit but forgot to knock out the plastic plug inside the dishwasher waste hose nipple on the disposal unit. First comment mentions ruling out the obvious problems like this one.